# How to use different interpolation syntax in freemaker template

Tags: bash, freemarker

I am working in a legacy codebase where the is existing code that uses `${...}` syntax for interpolation. Now I want to add some `bash` script which also happens to use `${}` in some places. Now there is a clash. I want to use a different interpolation syntax (ex: {{}}) for only those shell scripts. How to do that?

```bash
# sample script
.
.
command: /home/../schipt.sh ${datetime} <-- don't want to replace ${datetime}
```

Comment: Maybe add some sample of your input/code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an alternative, square bracket *interpolation* syntax, that you can enable with `Configuration.setInterpolationSyntax(SQUARE_BRACKET_INTERPOLATION_SYNTAX)`. With that FreeMarker interpolations are like `[=expression]`, instead of like `${expression}`.

See more here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html

There's a similar *tag* syntax setting, `setTagSyntax(SQUARE_BRACKET_TAG_SYNTAX)`, with which tags look like `[#assign x = 1]`, instead of `<#assign x = 1>`. That's independent of the interpolation syntax, but maybe you want to set both, so people will notice easier that we are in some non-default syntax (square brackets everywhere).

Comment: from the officvial documentation `it can't be specified inside the template`. Actually I don't have access to the configuration code, I can only modify templates. Also I don't want to use the ugly `${r"..."}` syntax

Comment: @Epsi95 You will have to reach the developers who can configure FreeMarker. They can even specify a name pattern (like `*.sh.ftl`) where square bracket syntax should be used, because they may want to use the default syntax elsewhere in the same singleton `Configuration`.